# CLLocation distanceFromLocation always return 0

Tags: cllocation

I'm having a problem when using the `distanceFromLocation` method, where it always returns zero.

Here's my code snippet:

```
NSArray *arrATMItem = [arrATMs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [arrATMItem objectAtIndex:0];

float lat = [[arrATMItem objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
float lon = [[arrATMItem objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
CLLocation *branchLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];

CLLocationDistance dist = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:branchLoc];
NSLog(@"distance = %d",dist);
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d m", dist];
```

I have also checked that the `branchLoc` and `currentLoc` instances have the right values.

Here's an example value of `branchLoc`:

lat: -6.17503957 long: 106.79891717

And a value for `currentLoc` is:

lat: -6.17603957 long: 106.79891717

The `branchLoc` values are retrieved from a plist file, and the `currentLoc` is obtained from the CLLocation class on the CLLocation `locationUpdate` method defined in my delegate file.

I tried using %f , and it also returns something like 0.00000.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I'm adding this comment for others because this is what happened to me. I was using test locations that I made up. However, they were invalid (I mixed up the lat and long). You can use the function `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(currentLocation.coordinate)` to determine if the coordinates are valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double  (or CLLocationDegrees) for lat and lon.